# Reading pixel from images using Haskell

Tags: haskell

Does anyone know how to read a pixel from images using Haskell? I am now using a juicy pixel as a library.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try Friday, a young but fun image processing library.

Comment: This question really shows minimal effort. I went to the [Hackage page for JuicyPixels](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels) and clicked the first thing that seemed relevant a few times (first the top-level module name, `Codec.Picture`, then the link that said "pixels" in the navigation menu at the top right) and had the answer.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I am very new to haskel and sometimes got confuse with the definition. I have browse through the library and did not understand what its say. that is why i am here.

Answer (score 1):

JuicyPixel provides the [`pixelAt`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/JuicyPixels-3.2.8.1/docs/Codec-Picture.html#v:pixelAt) function to get a pixel at a given coordinate.

```
pixelAt :: Image a -> Int -> Int -> a
```

> Extract a pixel at a given position, (x, y), the origin is assumed to be at the corner top left, positive y to the bottom of the image

Comment: Thanks Erik! It just i did not understand the definition. Haskell newbie!